# Magento 2.4.1: Uncaught Error: [object Object] at Object.<anonymous> (default.js:847)

Tags: javascript, jquery, frontend, magento-2.3

The error as the post title appears in the cart page. default.js is the bundle that I created with advanced JS bundling. You can see that this is where the error has originated from. When looking at the line that causes the error, it appears to be impossible to fix. I'm not sure why this js error shows up. Please advise as to what needs to be done to fix this.

[image]

Comment: `throw new error` [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/throw) should be passed a string, not an object.  That would fix the `throw` *message* and maybe let you see what the actual error is, which looks like, from the *screenshot* provided, a 400 bad request on the indicated url (but that might be a different error).

Comment: But I have never even touched the file that has the line 8474. I have no idea what it is about. All I did was to have built the advanced JS bundling on our Magento site